# Verb "geeitet" in an old scientific text

Tags: verb

I am looking for the modern version of this verb and its root "geeitet" from a text written in 1863.

This came up while searching for an etymology of the name of an acid by a chemist called Adolf von Baeyer. It is thought that he called *Barbitursäure*, after lady named *Barbara* who was a waitress in a hotel where he used to eat. He never mentions this, of course in a formal paper, but several books do make this claim (probably it is a hearsay).

> Dieser Gedanke hat mich bei der folgenden Arbeit **geeitet**, und ich habe mich zunächst bemüht, die Kenntnis des Materials zu vervollständigen. Man wird sehen, wie sich dasselbe in einfachster Weise um die Substanz N<sub>2</sub>C<sub>4</sub>O<sub>3</sub>H<sub>4</sub>, die ich Barbitursäure nennen will, gruppieren lässt und wie also die Frage nach der Konstitution der Harnsäure und ihrer Derivate auf die Untersuchung dieser Substanz zurückgeführt ist.

On Google Books:
[Adolf von Baeyer: "Untersuchungen über die Harnsäuregruppe: Mittheilungen aus dem ..., Volume 1", 1863](https://books.google.com/books?id=gMQ5AAAAcAAJ&dq=Dieser%20Gedanke%20hat%20mich%20bei%20der%20folgenden%20Arbeit%20geeitet&pg=PA2)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is simply a typo. It should be *geleitet* instead of *geeitet*. The infinitive is [*leiten*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/leiten), and in the given context, it means *guide* or *direct*.

> Der Gedanke hat mich geleitet. → The thought has guided me.